# Removing a child element using SimpleXML with namespaces

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_9069a2d7-491f-49ca-a13f-96c5bad39b14" IssueInstant="2010-04-06T16:27:34Z" Version="2.0">
  <saml:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">https://ssl.perquisite.net/memberweb/federation</saml:Issuer>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
      <Reference URI="#_9069a2d7-491f-49ca-a13f-96c5bad39b14">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
            <InclusiveNamespaces xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="#default saml ds xs xsi"/>
          </Transform>
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
        <DigestValue>QpoCI6jZFhQi+PuYM6UaFBL9KEU=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>X8X6qSUDKa3h3+/girXCeOVxo8=</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
      <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate>MIIB2...CieOpEo35g==</X509Certificate>
      </X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
  <saml:Subject>
    <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient">654d2065-6eed-401f-bf6d-a181117a5fb8</saml:NameID>
  </saml:Subject>
  <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2010-04-06T16:27:04Z" NotOnOrAfter="2010-04-06T16:28:04Z"/>
  <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2010-04-06T16:27:34Z">
    <saml:AuthnContext>
      <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:X509</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
    </saml:AuthnContext>
  </saml:AuthnStatement>
</saml:Assertion>
```

code:

`$xml` is set to the above xml.

```
$sxml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$sxml->registerXPathNamespace('saml', 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion');
$sxml->registerXPathNamespace('sig', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#');

$signodes = $sxml->xpath('/saml:Assertion/sig:Signature');
```

At this point I want to remove the sig:Signature node and all children from the
XML. I've tried:

```
$node = dom_import_simplexml($signodes[0]);
$node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
```

and:

```
foreach($signodes as $item) {
    $node = dom_import_simplexml($item);
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

and:

```
unset($signodes);
```

and:

```
foreach($signodes as $node) {
   unset($node);
}
```

and then getting back the XML with:

```
$Canonical = $sxml->asXML();
```

All of the above seem to have no effect on the resultant XML
(but do not give errors either).

Anyone have any clues as to why?

Comment: It looks correct to me. I'm going to try to duplicate it locally. Question gets an upvote because you actually posted exactly what you've tried and asked a clear question which is a rarity around here.

Comment: Your example where you go through the dom_import_simplexml and removechild works for me here: http://codepad.org/b4emqwCA

Comment: Thanks mkaatman, I've simplified the code for readability, so I assume it's something to do with my actual code with and the scope of the variables that's causing it to "revert".

Comment: Yep, i'd been a spanner later on in my code! And now it's fixed! Thanks for your time on this mkaatman! :D

Answer (score 0):

As you saw what mkaatman said,
php has a method removeChild. (http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php)

You can remove a child by example:
$node->parentNode->removeChild($node);

Comment: I already knew this, I was asking if it was possible to use it with namespaces. The answer is "yes it does", I'd made a mistake with my code.